# Associating an attribute to an object

Tags: python

I have the following program. I discovered the maximum age but how can I associate that age in my function with the respective person object I've created ?

```
class Info :


  def __init__ (self, first, last, height) :

    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.height = height


  def fullname (self) :

    return self.first + ' ' + self.last


person1 = Info ("A", "B", 178)
person2 = Info ("C", "D", 161)
person3 = Info ("E", "F", 170)
heights = [person1.height, person2.height, person3.height]

def highest_height (heights) :

  return max (heights)


print ("Displaying full names:", person1.fullname (), person2.fullname (), person3.fullname ())
print ("The highest height is {} cm.".format (highest_ (heights)))
```

Instead of printing the highest age is {} cm...

I want the highest person is ... with {} cm..

Comment: I'm confused, you don't seem to store any ages.

Comment: heights * sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
tallest = max([person1, person2, person3], key=lambda p: p.height)
```

will return you the tallest person because the `max` function takes a `key` that it uses to calculate that max.

---

From O/Ps comment:

You can avoid using `lambda` by making the key a standard python function

```
def metric(person):
    return person.height 

max([person1, person2, person3], key=metric)
```

Or more simply - keep track of the person and the height in a loop,

```
tallest_p, tallest_h = None, -1  # assuming people can not be negitive height ;) 
for person in [person1, person2, person3]:
    if person.height > tallest_h:
        tallest_p, tallest_h = person, person.height
```

Comment: the only way is by using lambda functions ?

Comment: I added a non-lambda way

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in a comment that you're wondering if there's a non-lambda way of doing this:

```
class Info :


  def __init__(self, first, last, height) :

    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.height = height


  def fullname(self) :

    return self.first + ' ' + self.last


person1 = Info ("A", "B", 178)
person2 = Info ("C", "D", 161)
person3 = Info ("E", "F", 170)
persons = [person1, person2, person3]
heights = [person1.height, person2.height, person3.height]

def highest_height(heights) :
  return max(heights)

def highest_person(persons):
    highest = max([p.height for p in persons])
    highest_persons = []
    for person in persons:
        if person.height == highest:
            highest_persons.append(person)
    return highest_persons


print ("Displaying full names:", person1.fullname(), person2.fullname(), person3.fullname())
print ("The highest height is {} cm.".format(highest_height(heights)))
print ("The highest person is {} with height {} cm.".format(highest_person(persons)[0].fullname(), highest_height(heights)))
```

Notice that `highest_person()` returns a `list` of all persons that have the highest size (this is because you could have multiple people who are the tallest if they are the same length)

Comment: Just fixed a bug in it, please re-copy.